# VB.NET - How do I find difference in dates in MM/DD format?

Tags: vb.net

If I have two dates

```
Dim date1 As String = 01/05
Dim date2 As String = 01/07

Dim date As Integer

Date = 2
```

How do I go about making sure that 2 handles month changes and just general dates in this format?

Comment: that is not valid VB code, and no idea what `var date = 2` is supposed to do, but you can use the `.Subtract()` method or in (real) VB just subtract them to get a `TimeSpan`: `myTs = myDt1 - myDt2`

Comment: (re: edit) just because you call your vars "date" doesnt make them valid `DateTime` types.  Those are just text and have no more meaning as Dates than "foo".

Comment: Yes thank you. I'm just stating that this is the way the code is. Sorry about the previous syntax, working in different languages can mess you up that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would parse the strings into `DateTime` values, then you can subtract them to get a `TimeSpan` value that is the difference. Use the `Days` property to get the whole days from the value:

```
Dim date1 As String = "01/05"
Dim date2 As String = "01/07"

Dim d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "MM'/'dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim d2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date2, "MM'/'dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Dim date As Integer = (d2 - d1).Days
```